# Generate many SSRS reports each one on a different sheet in one excel file (in c#)

Tags: c#, excel, reporting-services, ssis, reportingservices-2005

I'm working on a SSIS and SSRS project

I need a c# code  to generate an excel file that contains many sheets ( each one of them contains the report SSRS )

I used this tutorial and it worked but it gives me different excel files for each report

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/generate-ssrs-reports-from-a-ssis-package

Thanks in advance.

Comment: google search led me here to merge worksheets into a single workbook.. https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.XLS/Spire.XLS-Program-Guide/Excel-Merge-Merge-Excel-Files-into-One-with-C-VB.NET.html

Comment: create a master report that calls all your other reports as subreports, place each one in a rectangle and then set the pagename property of each rectangle to the sheet name you want in your excel file.

Comment: good idea @KeithL .I'm going to try it .I think it wil work.

Comment: @AlanSchofield  maybe I will try it later . Thanks anyway